# How the get binary solutions for everything in simple nn using sigmoid?

Tags: python, debugging, neural-network

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
training_set_inputs = a1
training_set_outputs = a2
random.seed(1)
synaptic_weights =2*random.random((218,1))-1
for iteration in xrange(10000):
    output=np.asarray(1/(1+exp(-(dot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights)))),dtype=np.float64)
    synaptic_weights+= dot(training_set_inputs.T,(training_set_outputs- output)*output*(1-output))
print float(1/(1+exp(-(dot(a3,synaptic_weights)))))
```

For some reason, all the outputs are either 1 or 0. I am a beginner, and am not able to fix this on my own. Can someone help?

I don't know, how to upload the data. It is a huge file with over 218 inputs.

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: python 2.7 i have all the required libraries up to date too.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what sort of output are you expecting? Are you building a classifier or what? Maybe post a small sample of your data. You should make your weights smaller (see: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init). Also, you don't have a learning rate parameter (multiply the second last line by a scalar `alpha ~= 1e-3`)